# PHP - Update database every 15 mins

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set up a database field with a number in it, every 15 that number would increase by, say 5... I was wondering if anyone can give me any insight into how to set this up, or documentation that will lead me in the right direction... I would provide some code but I fear i am already going in the wrong direction and it would just hinder this feed..

I know the logic will go something like this

- PHP Script that will generate a number and add to current total
- Connect to database
- Update Number
- disconnect from database
- use cronjob to execute script every 15 mins

Comment: Your logic will do exactly what you want. I don't understand what you need?

Comment: Well.. there is your answer. Use a cronjob that runs every 15 minutes and add a query that updates the database.

Comment: I guess i am mainly looking for an example of the script that would add 5 to the database field each time

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 3):

That is one way of doing it. Assuming it is mySQL, you can also [create an event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html).

Edit: Adding the example:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

Comment: It would be useful to put the example in the linked documentation here, as it is almost perfectly applicable to OP's problem.